# How to display uploaded image into the current selected div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to upload images directly into the selected div using [*jQuery File Upload*](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) plugin.
I have this grid where I want to upload photos:

```
<div id="grid">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

In each `div.box` I have a button for uploading images and a table for displaying file available for upload and the uploaded:

```
<div class="box">
    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        <span>Upload a photo</span>
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    </span>
    <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped">
        <tbody class="files"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I upload an image in the first div is displayed on the last div. My Test here: [index.html](http://domandar.com/upload/index.html)

How can I display the uploaded image into the current selected div?

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you so much and sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try this

```
$('.box').click(function() {
if ($(this).html() === 'click to add photo') {
    var src = prompt('what is the image address of what you wish to see')
        if(src!==null){
    $(this).html("<img src='" + src + "'/>")
      }else{
        $(this).html('click to add photo');
      }
} else {
    var src = prompt('what is the image address of what you wish to see')
    $(this).append("<img src='" + src + "'/>")
}
})
```

```
<div class="box">click to add photo</div>
<div class="box">click to add photo</div>
<div class="box">click to add photo</div>
<div class="box">click to add photo</div>
```

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: if you click on a certain div and put in the image address the image will appear in the div

Comment: This question is about **jQuery File Upload plugin**.

Comment: The question is asking how to put the image in the selected div

Comment: Yes, but image has to come from file input managed by jQuery upload plugin. Have you seen how this plugin works?

Comment: no I have not. If you could show me a fiddle or something that would show me how it works that would be greatly appreciated. That would help me improve my answer